# Cannot Display Sprites Above SK3DNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

I'm displaying some basic 3D geometry within my SpriteKit scene using an instance of SK3DNode to display the contents of a SceneKit scene, as explained in [Apple's article here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sk3dnode/displaying_3d_content_in_a_spritekit_scene).

I have been able to position the node and 3D contents as I want using SceneKit node transforms and the position/viewport size of the SK3DNode.

Next, I want to display some other sprites in my SpriteKit scene **overlaid on top of the 3D content**, but I am unable to do so: The contents of the SK3DNode are always drawn on top.

I have tried specifying the `zPosition` property of both the SK3DNode and the SKSpriteNode, to no avail.

From Apple's documentation on SK3DNode:

> Use SK3DNode objects to incorporate 3D SceneKit content into a
>   SpriteKit-based game. When SpriteKit renders the node, **the SceneKit
>   scene is animated and rendered first. Then this rendered image is
>   composited into the SpriteKit scene**. Use the scnScene property to
>   specify the SceneKit scene to be rendered.

*(emphasis mine)*

It is a bit ambiguous withv regard to z-order (it only seems to mention the *temporal* order in which rendering takes place).

I have put together a [minimal demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/SK3DNodeDemo); the relevant code is:

**1. SceneKit Scene**

```
import SceneKit
class SceneKitScene: SCNScene {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let box = SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        box.materials = [material]

        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        boxNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi/2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**2. SpriteKit Scene**

```
import SpriteKit
class SpriteKitScene: SKScene {

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        // Scene Background
        self.backgroundColor = .red

        // 3D Node
        let objectNode = SK3DNode(viewportSize: size)
        objectNode.scnScene = SceneKitScene()
        addChild(objectNode)
        objectNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

        let camera = SCNCamera()
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        objectNode.pointOfView = cameraNode
        objectNode.pointOfView?.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 60)
        objectNode.zPosition = -100

        // 2D Sprite
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 60))
        sprite.position = objectNode.position
        sprite.zPosition = +100
        addChild(sprite)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

...And the **rendered result** is:

[image]

*(I want the yellow rectangle **above** the green box)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I made a Technical Support Incident with Apple about this and they just got back to me. The solution is actually very very simple.*

> If you want 2D sprites to render on top of `SK3DNodes`, you need to stop the contents of the `SK3DNodes` from writing to the depth buffer.

---

To do this, you just need to set `writesToDepthBuffer` to `false` on the `SCNMaterial`.

```
...

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
material.writesToDepthBuffer = false

...
```

Boom. Works.

Comment: Thank you, great find! I guess **this** should be the accepted answer. This should be somewhere in the docs for SK3DNode. I guess if I had thoroughly read the SCNMaterial docs before hand, I **might** have figured it out.

Comment: But I wonder if doing this won’t hinder up the depth test performed between the various 3D objects rendered by the SK3DNode.

Comment: From the Apple engineer in a follow up:
"If you are ever curious about what might be going on behind the scenes with rendering issues like this, you can perform a [GPU Frame Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools/capturing_a_frame_using_a_breakpoint) to get an idea of what may be happening. In this case, you would see that the `SK3DNode` content is being written to the depth buffer, but other SK content is not, so no matter what the z-position of your sprites was, the `SK3DNode` was always “on top”."

Comment: Based on [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462545-writestodepthbuffer) for `writesToDepthBuffer`, it doesn't seem like it should affect the drawing order between the 3D objects, but it may affect performance as it'll be looking at the "depth information about the opaque objects behind them." Aka it may be doing more work? But if nothing is in the depth buffer, it might be fine?

Answer (score 1):

***Please note that this is just something I stumbled upon.* I have no idea why it works and I probably wouldn't trust it without further understanding, but maybe it'll help find an explanation or a real solution.**

---

It seems that having an `SKShapeNode` (with a fill) alongside an `SK3DNode` (either as a sibling, part of a sibling tree, or child), draws it in proper order. The `SKShapeNode` doesn't seem to need to intersect with the `SK3DNode` either.

The fill is important, as having a transparent fill makes this not work. Stroke doesn't seem to have any effect.

An `SKShapeNode` of extremely small size and almost zero alpha fill works too.

Here's my playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

let viewSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 150)
let viewportSize: CGFloat = viewSize.height * 0.75

func skview(color: UIColor, index: Int) -> SKView {
    let scene = SKScene(size: viewSize)
    scene.backgroundColor = color

    let view = SKView(
        frame: CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(index) * viewSize.height),
            size: viewSize
        )
    )
    view.presentScene(scene)
    view.showsDrawCount = true

    // Draw the box of the 3d node view port
    let viewport = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange, size: CGSize(width: viewportSize, height: viewportSize))
    viewport.position = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 2, y: viewSize.height / 2)
    scene.addChild(viewport)

    return view
}

func cube() -> SK3DNode {
    let mat = SCNMaterial()
    mat.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

    let box = SCNBox(width: viewportSize, height: viewportSize, length: viewportSize, chamferRadius: 0)
    box.firstMaterial = mat

    let boxNode3d = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    boxNode3d.runAction(.repeatForever(.rotateBy(x: 10, y: 10, z: 10, duration: 10)))

    let scene = SCNScene()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode3d)

    let boxNode2d = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: viewportSize, height: viewportSize))
    boxNode2d.position = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 2, y: viewSize.height / 2)
    boxNode2d.scnScene = scene

    return boxNode2d
}

func shape() -> SKShapeNode {
    let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: viewSize.height / 4, height: viewSize.height / 4))
    shape.strokeColor = .clear
    shape.fillColor = .purple
    return shape
}

func rect(_ color: UIColor) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let sp = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: color, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: viewSize.height / 4))
    sp.position = CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 2, y: viewSize.height / 2)
    return sp
}

// The original issue, untouched.
func v1() -> SKView {
    let v = skview(color: .red, index: 0)

    v.scene?.addChild(cube())
    v.scene?.addChild(rect(.yellow))

    return v
}

// Shape added as sibling after the 3d node. Notice that it doesn't overlap the SK3DNode.
func v2() -> SKView {
    let v = skview(color: .blue, index: 1)

    v.scene?.addChild(cube())
    v.scene?.addChild(shape())
    v.scene?.addChild(rect(.yellow))

    return v
}

// Shape added to the 3d node.
func v3() -> SKView {
    let v = skview(color: .magenta, index: 2)

    let box = cube()
    box.addChild(shape())

    v.scene?.addChild(box)
    v.scene?.addChild(rect(.yellow))

    return v
}

// 3d node added after, but zPos set to -1.
func v4() -> SKView {
    let v = skview(color: .cyan, index: 3)

    v.scene?.addChild(shape())
    v.scene?.addChild(rect(.yellow))

    let box = cube()
    box.zPosition = -1
    v.scene?.addChild(box)

    return v
}

// Shape added after the 3d node, but not as a sibling.
func v5() -> SKView {
    let v = skview(color: .green, index: 4)

    let parent = SKNode()
    parent.addChild(cube())
    parent.addChild(rect(.yellow))

    v.scene?.addChild(parent)
    v.scene?.addChild(shape())

    return v
}

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height * 5)))
container.addSubview(v1())
container.addSubview(v2())
container.addSubview(v3())
container.addSubview(v4())
container.addSubview(v5())

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
```

[image]

---

**TL;DR**

In your code, try:

```
...

let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 0.01, height: 0.01))
shape.strokeColor = .clear
shape.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.01)

// 3D Node
let objectNode = SK3DNode(viewportSize: size)
objectNode.addChild(shape)

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. In the end, I migrated my app to SceneKit, and implemented all the GUI using SKScenes overlaid using SCNView’s `overlaySKScene` property (SK3DNode also imposes limitations on what kind of visual effects you can render).

Comment: Sounds good, I'm thinking of going that route too. I don't feel comfortable using this hack lol. Fortunately I'm solely using UIKit for my GUI so that hasn't been an issue, but I need sprites to be rendered over some 3D objects in the game. Maybe someone who knows what's up will see this and shed some insight. Have you noticed any clear disadvantages with SceneKit for 2D heavy projects?

Comment: The only one I came across is, you can no longer use the SpriteKit scene transitions when your scenes are SceneKit view overlays. I wrote an article on Medium: https://medium.com/macoclock/an-simple-architecture-for-scenekit-games-part-1-4a5b84af79d1